# How to Keep a Window in Front of Others in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, window, gui

Does anybody know if it would be possible to keep a window in front of others on Mac OS X (10.6) ?

I would like to be able to have my firebug console open while debugging my site and my screen real estate is not big enough to have both sharing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.5min.com/Video/Mac-Tip-How-To-Keep-The-Window-On-Top-Of-Others-61115422

Describes an application that will force a chosen window to stay active on top of other windows.

Comment: nice, but doesn't work for snowLeopard.

Comment: oh, and the app is Afloat2 and available here: http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/

Comment: Did not realize it didn't work with 10.6. Good reason not to upgrade my MacPro.